# Finding shortest substring containing certain characters in linear time

Tags: python, string, algorithm

> Goal: implementing an algorithm that, given strings `a` and `b`, returns the shortest substring of `a` containing all characters of `b`. The string `b` can contain duplicates.

The algorithm is basically this one:
http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-the-smallest-window-in-a-string-containing-all-characters-of-another-string/

In the linked article, the algorithm finds only the length of the shortest substring, but that is a minor variation.

Here is my implementation:

import collections

```
def issubset(c1, c2):
    '''Return True if c1 is a subset of c2, False otherwise.'''
    return not c1 - (c1 & c2)


def min_idx(seq, target):
    '''Least index of seq such that seq[idx] is contained in target.'''
    for idx, elem in enumerate(seq):
        if elem in target:
            return idx


def minsub(a, b):
    target_hist = collections.Counter(b)
    current_hist = collections.Counter()
    # Skip all the useless characters
    idx = min_idx(a, target_hist)
    if idx is None:
        return []
    a = a[idx:]
    # Build a base substring
    i = iter(a)
    current = []
    while not issubset(target_hist, current_hist):
        t = next(i)
        current.append(t)
        current_hist[t] += 1
    minlen = len(current)
    shortest = current
    for t in i:
        current.append(t)
        # Shorten the substring from the front as much as possible
        if t == current[0]:
            idx = min_idx(current[1:], target_hist) + 1
            current = current[idx:]
            if len(current) < minlen:
                minlen = len(current)
                shortest = current
    return current
```

Unfortunately, it does not work. For example,

```
>>> minsub('this is a test string', 'tist')
['s', ' ', 'i', 's', ' ', 'a', ' ', 't', 'e', 's', 't', ' ', 's', 't', 'r', 'i', 'n', 'g'
```

What am I missing?
Side note: I'm not really sure that my implementation is O(n), but that is a different problem. As for now I'm looking to fix my implementation.

**EDIT:** Seemingly working solution:

```
import collections


def issubset(c1, c2):
    '''Return True if c1 is a subset of c2, False otherwise.'''
    return not c1 - (c1 & c2)


def min_idx(seq, target):
    '''Least index of seq such that seq[idx] is contained in target.'''
    for idx, elem in enumerate(seq):
        if elem in target:
            return idx


def minsub(a, b):
    target_hist = collections.Counter(b)
    current_hist = collections.Counter()
    # Skip all the useless characters
    idx = min_idx(a, target_hist)
    if idx is None:
        return []
    a = a[idx:]
    # Build a base substring
    i = iter(a)
    current = []
    while not issubset(target_hist, current_hist):
        t = next(i)
        current.append(t)
        current_hist[t] += 1
    minlen = len(current)
    shortest = current[:]
    for t in i:
        current.append(t)
        # Shorten the substring from the front as much as possible
        if t == current[0]:
            current_hist = collections.Counter(current)
            for idx, elem in enumerate(current[1:], 1):
                if not current_hist[elem] - target_hist[elem]:
                    break
                current_hist[elem] -= 1
            current = current[idx:]
            if len(current) < minlen:
                minlen = len(current)
                shortest = current[:]
    return shortest
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with this step, when we add a character to `current` and it matches the first character:

> remove the leftmost character and all other extra characters after left most character.

This value of `idx`

```
            idx = min_idx(current[1:], target_hist) + 1
```

is sometimes lower than the expected:  `idx` should increase as long as `current_hist` is a subset of `target_hist`.  So, we need to keep `current_hist` up to date to compute the right value for `idx`.  Also, `minsub` should return `shortest` instead of `current`.

```
def minsub(a, b):
    target_hist = collections.Counter(b)
    current_hist = collections.Counter()
    # Skip all the useless characters
    idx = min_idx(a, target_hist)
    if idx is None:
        return []
    a = a[idx:]
    # Build a base substring
    i = iter(a)
    current = []
    while not issubset(target_hist, current_hist):
        t = next(i)
        current.append(t)
        if t in target_hist:
            current_hist[t] += 1
    minlen = len(current)
    shortest = current
    #current = []
    for t in i:
        current.append(t)
        current_hist[t] += 1
        # Shorten the substring from the front as much as possible
        if t == current[0]:
            #idx = min_idx(current[1:], target_hist) + 1
            idx = 0
            while issubset(target_hist, current_hist):
                u = current[idx]
                current_hist[u] -= 1
                idx += 1
            idx -= 1
            u = current[idx]
            current_hist[u] += 1
            current = current[idx:]
        if len(current) < minlen:
            minlen = len(current)
            shortest = current[:]
    return shortest
```

```
In [9]: minsub('this is a test string', 'tist')
Out[9]: ['t', ' ', 's', 't', 'r', 'i']
```

Comment: Oh I get it! However, something must be still missing, because in the result the letter `i` is not present.

Comment: Finally I got it working, it seems. There was also a severe bug in the end: by doing `shortest = current` and then modifying `current`, `shortest` would change unexpectedly. The downside of my solution is that every time I reconstruct `current_hist`, when instead it could be modified along the way as you did. If you can suggest anything I'll be very grateful!

Comment: I updated my answer,  there were two more bugs: `shortest` should be copy: `shortest = current[:]` and the arguments of `issubset` were reversed.

Comment: Yeah exactly, thank you for your help! I was going crazy!